# Proving Continuous Pointwise Functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If you are given the piecewise defined function
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}x\sin(1/x),\quad x\neq 0\\0,\quad \quad \quad \quad x = 0,\end{cases}
$$
how do you go about proving that it is or is not continuous using the definition of continuity?

Answer (score 2):

Use the definition of continuity at a point. The points other than 0 will not pose a problem as the functions $x, \frac{1}{x}, \sin x$ are continuous outside of $0$.

To verify continuity at $0$, given any $\epsilon > 0$ choose $\delta =\epsilon$ such that whenever $|x - 0| < \delta (=\epsilon)$ we have $|f(x)-f(0)|=|f(x)| \le max\{0, |x \sin \frac{1}{x}|\}\le |x| < \epsilon$ since $|\sin \frac{1}{x}| \le 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the limit is equal to the value of the function at every point. At $0$, you have to use the squeeze theorem. Everywhere else, you can plug in.

Comment: I am looking for the more theoretical approach, using the definition of continuity

Comment: Epsilon-delta is easy; just note that $|x\sin(1/x)|\leq |x|$, so you can make $f(0)-0$ less than $\epsilon$ by choosing $\delta$ less than $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}x\sin(1/x),\quad x\neq 0\\0,\quad \quad \quad \quad x = 0,\end{cases}
$$

Check limit around zero , you will get $0* ~Oscillating[-1,1]$ in both the cases so RHL=LHL=$0$ and f(a)=0 so the function is continous at zero.